# Jupyter notebook opens slowly and extensions don't show up - [MathJax] issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I'm trying to open a jupyter notebook and it takes a long time and I see at the bottom it's trying to load various [MathJax] extension, e.g. at the bottom left of the safari browser it says:

Loading [MathJax]/extensions/safe.js

Eventually, the notebook loads, but the extensions I used to have, don't show up (like table of contents and others)

I tried to run `nbstripout` with the relevant filename but it didn't change anything.
I also tried to reinstall jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with timing (but my extensions all seem to work OK). After a lot of experiments with MathJax options in the Jupyter configuration file it seems to be... not related to MathJax.

My guess is that's the last notice displayed, and it stays there while the rest of the notebook loads.

In my experiments, the time to load is directly related to the number of cells in the notebook.